# Alternative proof that isomoprhisms between fundamental groups induce an homotopy equivalence between complete compact manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

As in the title if two complete compact manifolds of courvature $\leq 0$ have isomorphic foundamental groups there a homotopy equivalence between them that realise this isomorphism.

The classic proof (as far as I know) use the fact that what I said is true for aspherical cell complex, and that compact manifolds are aspherical cell complex; I'm writing a small essay and I wish to sue this results without having to deal with cell theory. I wish to find a proof that use directly the propriety of the manifolds without passing for the cell complex theory.

If someone know a demonstration, have an idea or some references will be great!

PS: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Absent other leads, I'd start by looking at the proof for aspherical cell complexes and seeing if I can adapt it to Morse theory.

Comment: The hard part is to construct a map inducing the given isomorphism of fundamental groups; in contrast, constructing homotopy is easy (use straight-line homotopy). One can avoid the difficult issue of existence of a triangulation (for constructing a map) by using nerves of locally finite covers by metric balls (and the associated partitions of unity). None of this will be quick and the idea is not that different from Whitehead's.

Comment: Compact manifolds are NOT aspherical complexes. Compact manifolds with curvature less than zero have universal cover diffeomorphic to euclidean space by Cartan-Hadamard and are hence aspherical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of the proof. If and when I have more time, I will update it.

Theorem. Let $M, N$ be closed Riemannian manifolds of nonpositive curvature. Then every isomorphism $\phi: \pi_1(M)\to \pi_1(N)$ is induced by a homotopy-equivalence $f: M\to N$.

Proof. I will  identify fundamental groups with the groups of covering transformations $G, H$ of the universal covering spaces $X, Y$ of $M$ and $N$ respectively.

Step 1. Pick a point $x\in X$. Since $M$ is compact, there exists $r>0$ such that the $G$-orbit of the metric ball $B(x,r)$ covers the entire $X$. Let ${\mathcal U}$ denote this cover, its elements $B(gx,r)$ are indexed by $g\in G$; let $X'$ denote the nerve of this cover; this is a $G$-space.  I will identify $X'$ with a subcomplex of an infinite-dimensional simplex whose vertex set is $G$. Let $\{\eta_g\}_{g\in G}$ be a $G$-invariant partition of unity on $X$ corresponding to ${\mathcal U}$. Using this partition of unity construct a $G$-equivariant continuous map $f_1: X\to X'$:
$$
x\mapsto \sum_{g\in G} \eta_g(x) \in X'. 
$$

Step 2. Let $f_2: Gx\to Y$ be an arbitrary $G$-equivariant map: It is defined by prescribing the image $f_2(x)\in Y$. This map $f_2$ can be regarded as a $G$-equivariant map from the vertex set of $X'$ to $Y$. Now, use **barycentric coordinates** on $Y$ to extend $f_2$ to a $G$-equivariant continuous map $X'\to Y$. (Here we use nonpositive curvature of $Y$.) More precisely, for each $n$-simplex $\Delta\subset X'$ and point $z\in \Delta$ with barycentric coordinates $(z_0,...,z_n)$, send $z$ to the unique point in $Y$ which has barycentric coordinates $(z_0,...,z_n)$ with respect to $f_2(v_0),..., f_2(v_n)$, where $v_i$'s are the vertices of $\Delta$. The barycentric maps to Riemannian manifolds were introduced by Karcher, see e.g. [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.3740.pdf) recent paper for the details.

Step 3. Composing $f_2\circ f_1$ we obtain an equivariant continuous map $X\to Y$. Similarly, construct an equivariant map $g: Y\to X$. Then the compositions $k:= f\circ g: Y\to Y$ and $l:= g\circ f: X\to X$ are equivariant maps with respect to $G$ and $H$ actions:
$$
k\circ h= h\circ k, l\circ g= g\circ l, \forall g\in G, h\in H. 
$$

Step 4. The maps $k, l$ are equivariantly homotopic to the identity maps $Y\to Y, X\to X$. To prove this, use the geodesic homotopy (here I again use nonpositive curvature):
$$
(p,t)\mapsto \gamma_{p, k(p)}(t),
$$
where $\gamma_{y_1,y_2}(t)$ is the constant speed geodesic defined on the unit interval and connecting $y_1$ to $y_2$. Since $Y$ is a hadamard manifold, this geodesic is a continuous function of $t, y_1, y_2$. Do the same for $X$.

Step 5. By equivariance, the maps $f, g$ and the homotopies descend to $M, N$. qed

Comment: It's more than enough, thank you very much.